# adding a guard rail to a flat roof

Tags: safety, brick, porch

So I have a flat roof that is was at some point a nice sun porch off of what is now an office. When we bought this house this summer we had the door to it replaced and in working in my office I cant help but think I'd rather work outside when I can.  I guess I'm curious about how to go about adding a railing to the roof itself.  The house is brick and I could attach brackets on the other side of the gutters and that would work but its going to look weird I'm not sure if I could add the railing directly to the roof but if I could I'd like to. Does anyone know how this is usually done?

** EDIT it is a concrete flat roof

Comment: Pictures of the roof might help.  From your description, I can't tell what the roof looks like or where you want to add the rails.

Comment: The question is unanswerable as it is. Much more detail about your structure is needed, and that will probably require good photos.

Comment: Are you wanting metal vs wood? Something merely for safety? What is the flooring material, if any, and what is beneath that?

Comment: The top few courses of brickwork in a cavity built wall are generally weak as they are not under much compression. If the concrete slab also sits onto the brickwork you can disregard this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets can be bolted through most roofing materials and into the concrete as long as they are properly sealed and indeed if the concrete is a suitable thickness to hold such bolts. Many stainless steel column and glass/wire/etc. combinations are commercially available.

However, keep in mind that the railing needs to be removable should the roofing material need replacing in the future and also drilling into concrete may be probelematical should you hit steel reinforcing bars or mesh.

Answer (score 1):

I would call a few fencing firms and have them give suggestions and pricing for a type of railing or fencing you like. The ones that have been in business for a long time have probably seen and installed any thing you can think of.